# Operation ParseExample not supported while converting SavedModel to TFLite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-lite

I am using TensorFlow estimator to train and save a model and then convert it in a .tflite. I saved the model as following:

```
feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('feature1'),
             tf.feature_column.numeric_column('feature2'),
             tf.feature_column.numeric_column('feature3'),
             tf.feature_column.numeric_column('feature4')]

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    """An input receiver that expects a serialized tf.Example."""
    feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feat_cols)
    default_batch_size = 1
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[default_batch_size], name='tf_example')
    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
    features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)


dnn_regressor.export_saved_model(export_dir_base='model',
                                 serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

When I try to convert the resulting .pb file using:

```
tflite_convert --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite --saved_model_dir=/tmp/saved_model
```

I get an exception saying that the ParseExample operation is not supported by the TensorFlow Lite.

> Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you might be able to use the extended runtime by passing --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are using: CONCATENATION, FULLY_CONNECTED, RESHAPE. Here is a list of operators for which you will need custom implementations: ParseExample.

If I try to **export the model without serializing**, when I try and predict on the resulting .pb file the function expects and empty set(), and not the dict of inputs that I am passing.

> ValueError: Got unexpected keys in input_dict: {'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4'}
>   expected: set()

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code that atempts to save the model without doing any serialization

```
features = {
    'feature1': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='feature1'),
    'feature2': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='feature2'),
    'feature3': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='feature3'),
    'feature4': tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='feature4')
}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, features)


dnn_regressor.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base='model', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn, as_text=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Using build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn I managed to export the saved model without any serialization:

```
serve_input_fun = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
    features,
    default_batch_size=None
)

dnn_regressor.export_savedmodel(
    export_dir_base="model",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serve_input_fun,
    as_text=True
)
```

**NOTE**: When doing prediction the Predictor doesn't know the default signature_def so I needed to specify it:

```
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model("model/155482...", signature_def_key="predict")
```

Also converting from .pb to .tflite I used the Python API because I needed to specify there also the signature_def:

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('model/155482....', signature_key='predict')
```